# how to set a facebook embed video to 100% width

Tags: css, facebook

I use the facebook embed plugin and it generates an iframe but I have a display issue only on mobile, It takes more than 100% width.

Here is my code :

```
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/20531316728/posts/10154009990506729/" data-width="auto" data-show-text="true">
     <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/20531316728/posts/10154009990506729/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
     </blockquote>
</div>
```

What can I do to have a 100% width iframe on mobiles devices ?

Thank you,
Merry xMas

Comment: You need to recreate the issue in a codepen or something similar. There's no possible way to debug your code as is

Comment: you can wrap it with your own wrapper with width:"100%" and create a method to calculate this 100% width in pixel and update the attribute data-width with your calculated width in pixel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround using a wrapper element:

```css
.fb-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
}

.fb-wrapper iframe {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="fb-wrapper">
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FGoogleDE%2Fvideos%2F801609183514998%2F&show_text=0&width=560" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

It uses padding as a hack to maintain ratio:
`padding-bottom = (height / width) * 100%`.

You need to calculate the ratio of your embed to get this to work. In my example (width="560" height="315") the ratio is to be calculated as follows:
`315px / 560px = 0.5625 = 56.25%`

Credit: I copied this from a [snippet by Valentin Garcia](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/responsive-facebook-videos/) once.