# Force Facebook to Use Style

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I am trying to force a Facebook Embed to take up half the page. Normally in CSS, I would do `width: 50%`, but Facebook seems to cap the max pixels at 500, but I don't want that to happen. Is there a work-around for this?

Heres my current code:

```css
iframe{
  width: 100%; /*should take up the entire container, instead takes up 500px*/
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Feliotfiskguitar&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="340" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>
```

As you can see in the snippet, it should be taking up the entire page, but it instead takes up 500px.

I also tried using JQuery to calculate the width of the page and set the `data-width` attribute to the width in pixels, but again, it was capped at 500px.

Help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set a facebook embed video to 100% width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53870037/how-to-set-a-facebook-embed-video-to-100-width)

Comment: @RaheelJunaid sadly it does not work. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is anything you can fix. I think this is a problem with Facebook, not with your code. If you absolutely **need** to fix this, I would suggest either setting up a custom `div` or other HTML elements and putting it all in an `iframe`, customizing it yourself and adding links that go to their Facebook page.

When I go to the [link that is inside of the frame](https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Feliotfiskguitar&tabs=timeline&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId), it also does not give me the correct size.

Sorry we couldn't help, but I don't think there's any other way, and I'm not particularly familiar with Facebook's API anyway.